# Routing traffic on two NICs

Tags: macos, network

I have a Mac with two NICs.

- Interface #1 is on VLAN blue, with IP 10.41.0.18
- Interface #2 is on VLAN red, with IP 192.168.38.16

Both VLANs are separated, interface #1 is the main one.

On the Mac, I have an application that must be able to communicate with a bunch of specific IPs on both VLAN blue and red.

Is there a way I can route traffic on interface 1 or 2, depending on the IP called by the application?

Comment: To have both networks talk to each other, you have to set up the correct routing tables using the `route` command.  Now, this has a limitation where only the *destination* can have an individual host defined. In other words, you can’t filter certain hosts to be routed and not others.  To do what you want, you will need to implement rules using the `pf` firewall

Comment: Thx Allan; if the main interface is en1, would such a command make sense ? 
`route add -host 192.168.38.16 -interface en1`

Comment: I do not really want to have both network talk to each other but rather being able to store files coming from other systems using en0 and then push them on a specific host through en1. Context: DICOM transfer (medical imaging), network troubleshooting and last minute workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately, for one host on one network to talk to another host on a different network, both networks *must* talk to each other.  That’s just the reality of it. To limit the number of hosts that will communicate to/from one network to another, you need a firewall that can filter hosts via rules.  Your other option is to make the individual hosts members of both VLANS.  That means multiple network adapters  or adapters that are VLAN capable.

Comment: Can a Mac Pro with two Ethernet ports be connected on two networks on the same time and push files on both of them ? Sorry if it is a silly question, but why do we have workstations with two connectors then ?

Comment: Yes.  By default the Mac will know about both networks and should route accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you want is simply the default behavior on macOS (and other major operating systems).

You will have two network interfaces in macOS - one with the 10.41.0.18 IP address and one with the 192.168.38.16 address. The principle is the same no matter if you just connect each network to a separate network port on the Mac Pro, or you have a single network cable connected with multiple VLANs on.

When an application running on the Mac wants to communicate with an IP address on either network, the data will be routed according to your routing table.

I don't know your specific network, but from your IP addresses, you'll probably have something like:

```
  network 1: 10.41.0.0/8 (255.0.0.0)
  network 2: 192.168.38.0/24 (255.255.255.0)
```

This means that packets destined for an IP address of the form 10.41.xxx.xx will go out the network 1 interface, and packets destined for an IP address on the form 192.168.38.xxx will go out the network 2 interface.

Your subnet masks might vary slightly, but this is the general idea.

Usually you'll also have a default gateway defined on one network interfaces. IP addresses that do not fall in those two sub-networks above will be routed to the default gateway instead over that particular network interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Now I have an IP on 10.42.nnn.nnn which is only accessible using the network 2. How can I force the OS to use network 2 for that ?

Comment: It would be easier to guide you, if you could provide specifics on your network setup - i.e. subnet masks, etc. However in general: If your network masks are setup so that 10.42.nnn.nnn is a different network than 10.41.nnn.nnn, then you can just make sure your default gateway is set for the network 2 gateway. If that is not the case, you need to add an entry to the routing table. You can do that manually with a Terminal command - or if this is a more permanent solution for general usage, you can configure your DHCP server on network 2 to include that extra route.

Comment: To add the static route manually using the Terminal, you would write a command something like this: "route -n add -net 10.42.0.0/16 192.168.38.1". This assumes that you want to route every 10.42.nnn.nnn address, and that your router on network 2 has IP 192.168.38.1 (it might have a different IP, but that's the most common IP for it).

Comment: You could choose to only route a single host (a single IP) - then the command would look like this instead: "route -n add -host 10.42.0.88 192.168.38.1". This assumes that the the specific IP you want to reach on network 2 is 10.42.0.88.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanations. Thanks to them I’ve been able to achieve exactly what I wanted. Last question: can we make that persistant after reboot ?